# Installing Magento security patch SUPEE 6285 - v 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to install the **SUPEE 6285** on **Magento v 1.9.0.1**

We do not have a SSH to our server. When I try to Method 1 found on [magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-security-patches/](http://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-security-patches/) I get a blank page when I run the patch on the browser.

After looking at the FAQS I see that I should have an `install.php` file under `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php` however I don't have a Router directory.

Any advise on how to install the patch?

Answer (score 0):

**First solution (recommended):**

Use Magento connect and upgrade your store to the latest Magento version by `check for upgrades`. The latest version contains this security patch (SUPEE 6285) and another features all together.

**Second Solution (Install patch manually):**

Download SUPEE 6285 - v 1.9.0.1_**v2**

Use an FTP client to upload the specific patch to the root of your Magento folder.
Create a PHP file called applypatch.php that will run the patch for you.
upload it to the root of your Magento folder. Make sure to use the right patch name here.

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.0.1_v2.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

Visit the file at http://yourdomain.com/applypatch.php, and check if the output looks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no 'easy' way to install these patches without shell access, but there's two ways to do it.

## Install patch through PHP

1. Use an FTP client to upload the specific patch to the root of your Magento folder.
2. Create a PHP file called magentopatch.php that will run the patch for you, and upload it to the root of your Magento folder. Make sure to use the right patch name here, if you don't use the patch for version 1.8.x-1.9.x

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

3. Visit the file at `http://your.domain.com/magentopatch.php`, and check if the output looks as expected.

## Install patch manually

The .sh file contains a 'DIFF' patch. These show what lines were removed and added. While I don't advise it, you should be able to manually download the files through FTP, and edit these files in your editor of choice, and then reupload them again through FTP.
The format isn't too hard to [interpret](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified), so you can do this for all the files and shouldn't take more then a few minutes.